# Materialize inputfields safari

Tags: css, materialize

I have an issue with materialize on Safari.

On chrome it works fine but on Safari i have this problem: 
[image: safari problem]

Is there anyone else with the same bug?

H

Comment: Any piece of code would be great.

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: I have answered below with my code.

Comment: @Julian can you see my code below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I used not the right syntax from Materialize. 
You must put the .input-field and .col in the same div.

Here is the code that is wrong:

```
   <div class="row">
 <div class="col s12">
    <div class="input-field">
       <textarea placeholder="Meeting Room Description" id="meeting_room_description" name="meeting_room[description]" class="materialize-textarea"><%= @general_params['description'] %></textarea>
       <label for="meeting_room_description">Description</label>
   </div>
 </div>
```

This is the right code:

```
   <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
       <textarea placeholder="Meeting Room Description" id="meeting_room_description" name="meeting_room[description]" class="materialize-textarea"><%= @general_params['description'] %></textarea>
       <label for="meeting_room_description">Description</label>
   </div>
```